# How To Get Access Control List For An Msmq Using C#

Tags: c#, msmq

Is it possible to get all permission list related with the given Msmq private queue via c#? ,

I see `MessageQueue.SetPermissions` and  `MessageQueue.ResetPermissions` but I don't see anything for getting the current permissions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to get the ACL for a queue with .NET Framework. The System.Messaging namespace lacks a lot of functionality otherwise found in the COM components for MSMQ, but unfortnately you can't even use COM for this.

If you are comfortable with P/Invoke you can use the method MQGetQueueSecurity
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703223(v=vs.85).aspx